# "Rebuild with Bitcode" and optional dependencies

Tags: ios, release, bitcode

I'm distributing 2 frameworks A and B. They can work together, but A can also work without B.

A contains some code checking if B exists and act accordingly. So A has an optional dependencies on B.

This seems to work well, but some days ago a client told me that with the Bitcode version when you try :

- Using only framework A with cocoapod
- exporting an Ad-hoc ipa
- while enabling "Rebuild with bitcode"

It will fail saying that it doesn't find B. "Could not resolve @rpath in @rpath/B.framework/B from A"

It doesn't seems to be an issue without bitcode. Obviously you can't rebuild with it, but you can put it on the store without bitcode.

Is there anything I should do for the bitcode case to be sure that B is REALLY optional and doesn't pose any issue when using only A?

Thank you in advance for the time of whoever will read this :)

Comment: I ended up building 2 versions of A, one of them without any references to B. But it's not a good long term solution :(

Comment: And back with the same issue with C now ;/